# How do I get my iTerm prompt to display differently when I'm in a Git branch?

Tags: git, macos, bash, iterm

I'm trying to get my iTerm prompt set up the same way as [Paul Irish](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXpCB3U_4Ig&t=10m39s)

So far I have the following in `~/.profile`:

```
# Add git branch name to prompt
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/*\(.*\)/ on \1/'
}

PS1='\n\[\033[0:35m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[033[0m\]$(parse_git_branch)\n\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

I don't know how to make just the branch appear in a different colour and not the preceding "on"

As well as this there are other features such as:

- Displaying an "o" at the prompt when not in a git branch
- Displaying a "±" when in a branch
- Displaying the date at the end of the line

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just as a tip: there is https://github.com/djl/vcprompt to do the whole git parsing for you. It also supports different vcs systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just written a post about how to do all this.  I've covered all the basics but had to guess a couple of things, e.g. how Paul uses the symbols etc.  If you want to read it, check out http://digitalformula.net/articles/pimp-my-prompt-like-paul-irish.

There's also an article on digitalformula.net that shows a couple of other prompt examples - see http://digitalformula.net/articles/a-couple-more-bash-prompt-examples.

EDITED: 
The code part is as follows:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/Data/Scripts:~/Data/Utils/rar:~/_Applications:~/_Applications/lynx

# alias to quickly show if any Handbrake processes are running
alias hb='sudo ps -aef | grep HandBrakeCLI'

# alias for quick DNS cache flushing
alias fc='sudo dscacheutil -flushcache'

# enable the git bash completion commands
source ~/.git-completion

# enable git unstaged indicators - set to a non-empty value
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE="."

# enable showing of untracked files - set to a non-empty value
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES="."

# enable stash checking - set to a non-empty value
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE="."

# enable showing of HEAD vs its upstream
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"

BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
POWDER_BLUE=$(tput setaf 153)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)

# set the prompt to show current working directory and git branch name, if it exists

# this prompt is a green username, black @ symbol, cyan host, magenta current working directory and white git branch (only shows if you're in a git branch)
# unstaged and untracked symbols are shown, too (see above)
# this prompt uses the short colour codes defined above
# PS1='${GREEN}\u${BLACK}@${CYAN}\h:${MAGENTA}\w${WHITE}`__git_ps1 " (%s)"`\$ '

# this is a cyan username, @ symbol and host, magenta current working directory and white git branch
# it uses the shorter , but visibly more complex, codes for text colours (shorter because the colour code definitions aren't needed)
# PS1='\[\033[0;36m\]\u@\h\[\033[01m\]:\[\033[0;35m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[1;30m\]\[\033[0;37m\]`__git_ps1 " (%s)"`\[\033[00m\]\[\033[0;37m\]\$ '

# return the prompt prefix for the second line
function set_prefix {
    BRANCH=`__git_ps1`
    if [[ -z $BRANCH ]]; then
        echo "${NORMAL}o"
    else
        echo "${UNDERLINE}+"
    fi
}

# and here's one similar to Paul Irish's famous prompt ... not sure if this is the way he does it, but it works  :)
# \033[s = save cursor position
# \033[u = restore cursor position

PS1='${MAGENTA}\u${WHITE} in ${GREEN}\w${WHITE}${MAGENTA}`__git_ps1 " on %s"`${WHITE}\r\n`set_prefix`${NORMAL}${CYAN}\033[s\033[60C (`date "+%a, %b %d"`)\033[u${WHITE} '
```

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow so just wondering ... is it protocol to include code in a response instead of a link?  I was hoping people would read the article instead of getting the code here as there are  a couple of things you need to do before the code above will work.

Comment: @SiegeX care to mention the original source?

Comment: @pablasso yea, me :)  Looking back at this I have overreacted a bit. Still would have been nice to get a mention that the color codes were from me but the whole plagiarism is over the top and I take that back.

Comment: I had line wrapping issues with iTerm2 and the date at the end of the line so have shuffled it to after the directory/branch info

`code`PS1='${MAGENTA}\u${WHITE} in ${GREEN}\w${WHITE}${MAGENTA}`__git_ps1 " on %s"`${WHITE} (`date "+%a, %b %d"`)\r\n`set_prefix`${NORMAL}${CYAN}\033[s\033[60C \033[u${WHITE} '`code`

Comment: Here's Paul Irish's actual configuration: https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_prompt

It is `source`d from his `.bash_profile`: https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile

Answer (score 23):

I use [git-aware-prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt).

A lot of solutions I had before only displayed the git branch if I were only in that directory when the terminal loaded. If I started iTerm in a non-git repo, then it wouldn't work when I `cd` into directory with a git repo.

This github project solved that for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is by far the easiest way to go about it and should be higher up.

Comment: Had some troubles using the other solutions, this is indeed the easiest one. Thanks

Comment: i also had the issue where the prompt would not change when i changed branches within a repo, this fixed it. also, incredibly easy to setup/configure.
thank you for sharing.  bill

Answer (score 9):

Rather than using archaic terminal codes, use `tput` instead which makes the code much easier to read and a lot harder to mess up:

```
BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
POWDER_BLUE=$(tput setaf 153)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)

# Set Titlebar and Prompt
TITLEBAR='\e]0;\h: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\a'
PS1="${TITLEBAR}${WHITE}[${POWDER_BLUE}\u@\h${WHITE}]${NORMAL}$ "
```

Setting the titlebar is optional. Just be sure to use `${NORMAL}` at the end to turn off the color change.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w on\e[0;35m$(__git_ps1)\e[m\$ "
```

Where,

`$(__git_ps1)` is used for printing the branch name

`\e` defines the start of the color scheme

`[0;35m` represent the purple color

`\e[m` defines the end of the scheme

**Also**, I fixed your current prompt:

```
PS1='\n\[\033[0;35m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[0m\]$(__git_ps1)\n\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

Comment: I recommend reading this page for coloring the prompt, since it can be applied to Mac too: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/

Comment: If you really like colors: `PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[36m\]@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\e[1;35m$(__git_ps1)\e[m \$ "`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using single quotes here, not double quotes.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, I also use [git-aware-prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt).

Run this to quickly install:

```
mkdir ~/.bash
cd ~/.bash
git clone git://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt.git
```

Add this to the top of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export GITAWAREPROMPT=~/.bash/git-aware-prompt
source "${GITAWAREPROMPT}/main.sh"
```

In the same file `~/.bash_profile` here is the prompt I use:

```
export PS1="\n\[$txtpur\]\u\[$bldwht\]@\h\[$bldgrn\]:\[$bldblu\] \w \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ \[$txtwht\] "

export SUDO_PS1="\[$bakred\]\u@\h\[$txtrst\] \w\$ "
```

you can change the [colors to your liking](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt/blob/master/colors.sh)

> Here is what some of the symbols in PS1 mean:
>   \u          - username
>   @           - cool symbol
>   \h          - hostname
>   :           - cool symbol to separate things
>   \w          - full path, use \W for short path
>   \git_branch - name of current branch
>   \git_dirty  - show * when there is a change in branch
>   $           - cool symbol to signify, enter command

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

A very feature rich and broad solution (not only for iterm shell but also for Vim and others) is [Powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/).